# any more efficient function than ContainsAny?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

```
 prob[tot_, sub_] := 
 Length[Select[Subsets[Range[tot], {5}], ContainsAny[Range[sub]]]]/
 combinat[tot, 5]   enter code here
```

this works but as tot goes up, say 60 it takes time, and cpu can warm coffee, so my questions is ContainsAny ... looks like the bottleneck .. is there a more efficient way ?

Comment: `IntersectingQ` seems to be faster than `ContainsAny`

Comment: What is it you're actually after, seems like an x-y question...
In any case, use inclusion-exclusion, or just do it directly:
`pr[t_,s_]:=1/120 s (24+s^4-5 s^3 (-2+t)+5 (-4+t) t (5+(-4+t) t)-5 s (-2+t) (5+2 (-4+t) t)+5 s^2 (7+2 (-4+t) t))`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`Binomial`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Binomial.html):

```
prb[tot_, sub_] := 1 - Binomial[tot - sub, 5]/Binomial[tot, 5]
```

Comment: Excellent ... you really know the ropes and the knots!  I pretended to make same rule trying with small sets ... but don't arrive to any rule at analitic way and moved to brute force...   Thanks